# Adaptative layout with css

Tags: html, css, mobile

I was attempting to create an adaptative css layout, i need learn a lot of thing yet then all help is welcome. There is an example about adaptative [here](http://2011.dconstruct.org/). In my fiddler nothing work, there is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRmT3/25/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is. But if you are asking why your columns aren't lining up correctly it's due to math.

You have them set to a width of 45% with a 3% margin (plus a border). 45 + (2*3) = 51%. You can't have two columns each of 51% fit into 100% of space.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/adaptive-responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) a tutorial on how to implement an adaptive layout to get you started. it also provides sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [fiddle, slightly updated](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/UzNaQ/).

As [DA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234931/adaptative-layout-with-css/7235035#7235035) already pointed out, the with's of `HHalfBarLft` and `HHalfBarRgt` where too large, so they did not fit next to each other.

Furthermore, you don't have to use `position: absolute` on the `ct` div: just add a clearing element inside it to (like a `HFullBar`) make the height stretch as you want.

And when you delete all positioned elements, then the footer stays in place also just fine.